# How to create a Stack in AWS via Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

My goal is to be able to create a 'stack' in AWS, i.e a grouping of related resources I can update and change using Terraform.

I've been attempting to read the documentation but I'm a little confused as to how I could accomplish this in terraform.

I understand the concept of possibly writing modules which are reusable, but I'm used to dealing with CF stacks when using AWS.
Is there an idiomatic way to do this in terraform? It seems that maybe the concept of a stack is abstracted away somewhat. i.e if I want to get and output from a resource.. eg a RDS url, I can reference that in the Terraform code and it will evaluate and determine it at runtime rather than reading a CF stack output value in AWS?

Is this correct?

Comment: Out of curiosity is there a reason you're making CloudFormation in Terraform? :)

Comment: Sorry I'll fix that up, I just want to create a stack. In the aws console it's under cloud formation -> stack. I just want to create a stack , or know if that's the right thinking for terraform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you are wanting to understand how to write a replica of a "stack" in Terraform and want to understand the concepts.

There are great number of resources for seeing example stacks, take a look at the [official Terraform AWS examples](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/tree/master/examples/elb) to get a feel for notation.

You're describing modules etc which are best practice, however start small. Add to your `main.tf` file a simple infrastructure and then build on that.

The best way to learn will be through doing, but take it at a steady pace.

And yes you can reference your resources, generally before you run `terraform apply` everything is evaluated. Any resource dependencies will be created in order.

Comment: I'm not just interested in writing a replica of a stack.. can you actually create a 'stack' using tf? i.e see it in the aws console under cloudformation -> stacks

Comment: Yes you can, use this: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudformation_stack.html and just specify your body.

Comment: So just to clarify, you can create a stack, but you have to specify the cloudformation in the body .. resources etc. Terraform seems to abstract the concept away via modules. Thanks for the info

Comment: You can use modules, these generally are to create components that create your entire stack. In CloudFormation terms its the equivalent of nested stacks :)